# Chai testing an undefined that should not throw TypeError

Tags: javascript, chai

I am trying to test a function that when an undefined variable is passed in, it should not throw TypeError:

```
describe('myFunction', function () {
    it('should not throw TypeError =>', function () {
        var x = undefined;
        chai.expect(myFunction(x)).to.not.throw(TypeError)
    }):
});
```

But it still throws the error.

Comment: @Phil, i need to not throw, the duplicate that you are suggesting are for cases when you want to throw an error.

Comment: Sounds like your function fails this test then. In any case, you should still pass a function to `expect()` so your assertion can operate on the result, even if it does throw an error

Comment: I pass myFunction(x) at expect(), and x is a undefined variable.

Comment: I don't think you've looked closely enough at the duplicate. Try `expect(() => myFunction(x))` or `expect(function() { myFunction(x) })` if you don't like arrow functions

Comment: You are correct. Thanks :)